# Android native animation gets slow when cleaver webview has heavy content

Tags: android, webview, cordova, android-animation, objectanimator

I am using translation animation using `ObjectAnimation` class in my Phonegap cleaver project. 

 I have a webview which shows the web content and I have made a plugin which slides down a menu on native side using translation animation.

My problem is that when my webview has heavy graphics content, my native menu lags while translation. 

I am having hardware acceleration ON and i am using similar code as below for translation.

```
Handler handler =new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        menuView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menuView, "translationY", -menuHeight, 0.0f);
        animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                menuView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null);
            }
        });
        animator.start(); 
   }
});
```

Please guide me how i can remove this lag.

 Note: this is not the actual code, just to give you a glance how i am doing it.